# OpenGL vertex shader is fast on Linux, but extremely slow on Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, vertex-attributes

To draw power spectral density of a signal (which is very similar to heatmap), I use this vertex shader program. It receives value of power at each vertex, takes logarithm to show result in dB, normalizes within the range of colormap array, and assigns a color to vertex.

```
#version 130

uniform float max_val;
uniform float min_val;
uniform int height;

attribute float val; // power-spectral-density value assigned to each vertex

// colormap values
const float r[512] = float[]( /* red values come here */ );
const float g[512] = float[]( /* green values come here */ );
const float b[512] = float[]( /* blue values come here */ );

void main() {
  // set vertex position based on its ID
  int x = gl_VertexID / height;
  int y = gl_VertexID - x * height;
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(x, y, -1.0, 1.0);

  float e = log(max_val / min_val);
  float d = log(val / min_val);

  // set color
  int idx = int(d * (512 - 1) / e); // find normalized index that falls in range [0, 512)
  gl_FrontColor = vec4(r[idx], g[idx], b[idx], 1.0); // set color
}
```

Corresponding C++ code is here:

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram glsl_program;
// initialization code is omitted

glsl_program.bind();
glsl_program.setUniformValue(vshader_max_uniform, max_val);
glsl_program.setUniformValue(vshader_min_uniform, min_val);
glsl_program.setUniformValue(vshader_height_uniform, max_colormap_height);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colormap); // colormap is a vector that contains value of power at each vertex
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, vertices_length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr); // vertex_length is size of colormap
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glsl_program.release();
```

This program runs fast enough on Linux. But in Windows, it is very slow and takes a lot of CPU time. If I change this line of GLSL:

```
// int idx = int(d * (512 - 1) / e);
int idx = 0;
```

then the app runs fast on Windows too. So, It has to be a problem with GLSL code.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Having arrays of that size hardcoded in a shader doesn't sound like a good idea. Especially for a colormap I would use a texture for that. Since you are talking about **CPU** time. Are you sure that the shader is the real problem? If you change to `idx = 0` also `d, e, min_val, max_val, val` are not used anymore and might get optimized away. So your problem can also be with uniforms/attributes.

Comment: This is a really good point, it's more common to sample from a texture when you need an array of values like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing there belongs into the fragment shader, not the vertex shader. And you submit both the color lookup table and the spectral density data as a texture. Although vertex setup is not *that* expensive, it comes with a certain overhead and in general you want to cover as many pixels with the least number of vertices possible.

Also learn logarithm calculation rules (e.g. `log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b)`) and avoid doing calculations that are uniform over the whole draw call and precalculate on the host.

```
/* vertex shader */
#version 130

varying vec2 pos;    

void main() {
  // set vertex position based on its ID
  // To fill the viewport, we need just three vertices
  // of a rectangular triangle of with and height 2
  pos.x = gl_VertexID % 2;
  pos.y = gl_VertexID / 2;

  // screen position is controlled using glViewport/glScissor
  gl_Position = vec4(2*pos, 0, 1.0);
}
```

-

```
/* fragment shader */
#version 130

varying vec2 pos;

uniform sampler2D values;
uniform sampler1D colors;

uniform float log_min;
uniform float log_max;

void main() {
  float val = texture2D(values, pos).x;
  float e = log_max - log_min;
  float d = (log(val) - log_min) / e;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(texture1D(colors, d).rgb, 1.0); // set color
}
```

In later versions of GLSL some keywords have changed. Varyings are defined using `in` and `out` instead of `varying` and texture access functions have been unified to cover all sampler types.

```
glsl_program.bind();
glsl_program.setUniformValue(vshader_log_max_uniform, log(max_val));
glsl_program.setUniformValue(vshader_log_min_uniform, log(min_val));

// specify where to draw in window pixel coordinates.
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glViewport(x, y, width, height);
glScissor(x, y, width, height);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, values_texture);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ..., spectral_density_data);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glsl_program.release();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me like a hero!